# LADP authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I want authenticate users from Active Directory, I want to pass username and password to Active Directory. I have below LDAP URL:

```
       ldap://LDAPS-NPR.TCSNPR.LOCAL:636
```

Please suggest how can I create PrincipalContext, I tried below but not working.

```
       PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,null,"ldap://LDAPS-NPR.TCSNPR.LOCAL:636");
       bool isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

I am getting below exception in principalContext

```
       ConnectedServer = 'principalContext.ConnectedServer' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException'
```

Comment: What is the exception message? And if the Authentication Server is known you dont need to add the ldap address, you just can name it. `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, youdomainname)`. It's also wise to wrap the creation and validation of the principal context into a using statement.

Comment: then what is the use of this ldap url?

Comment: in case you need to communicate with a very specific domain server (i. e. in PCI environments) or if the domain server is unknown to the machine where the code is being executed from